# How to upgrade or add new logic on smart contract allready deployed

Tags: proxy, upgrade, ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a smart contract has been deployed and i want to add some logic on this contract.

I was search and learn sample and tutorials about upgrades smart contract,  but nothing I understand and give a clear example. I just figured out how to create an upgradeable contract, and that's just an example of creating a new upgradeable contract.

Any tutorial or some code to updates smartcontract allready deployed.

Example smart contract : 0x31d176A37E2EC3bc986f5D3b23CE76e48d963F29 on binance smart chain tesnet. testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x31d176A37E2EC3bc986f5D3b23CE76e48d963F29

I want to add new logic on contract launchpool.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It is impossible to upgrade a contract that is already deployed and wasn't designed to be upgraded. The point of a smart contract is that it's immutable and thereby trustworthy once its code was examined, since it cannot be changed or hacked unless there was a bug in the code to begin with. Upgradable contracts usually work by delegating the actual execution of its functions to other contracts and making the delegation targets chanheable by the owner.

Comment: any solution for it?

Comment: No, as I wrote: it is impossible to upgrade a non-upgradeable contract. There is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you don't.

Answer (score 0):

This just goes against the principle of immutability of Blockchain. Smart Contracts once deployed cannot be changed. If you want to add new logic then you also need to deploy it again and interact with that one